# How to show selenium browser in VNC after creating it over SSH with a virtual display

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, vnc

I created a selenium browser over SSH using
like so

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1920, 1920))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

I then logged into the machine with VNC. And my goal is to move the chrome window created there onto my VNC session. However that instance of chrome doesn't even show up in the task bar even though I can tell it is open and even interact with it.

I connected via

```
webdriver.Remote(command_executor=bla,options=options)
```

And I did try

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.current_window_handle)
```

But that didn't work. I even tried

```
driver.switch_to.window(webdriver.Chrome().current_window_handle)
```

But this gave me a `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException`

Answer (score 0):

by default, [manage_global_env is True](https://github.com/ponty/PyVirtualDisplay/blob/1d0335836d1673ec8b872debf58cf2d862c5d54d/pyvirtualdisplay/xvnc.py#L26)
so `pyvirtualdisplay.Display()`
will set `os.environ["DISPLAY"]` to the virtual display

webdriver will use `subprocess.Popen`
with the environment `os.environ` to start chrome

so this should just work...

```py
import os
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

print("main script is running on display", os.environ.get("DISPLAY"))

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1920, 1920))
display.start()

print("starting chrome on display", os.environ.get("DISPLAY"))
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```